# Word - Disable boxes around paragraphs

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

**Issue**:

Everytime I open a new blank document in Word it brings up some sort of template/style which looks like a table but seemingly isn't an actual table. Every <kbd>Enter</kbd> stroke brings up another line of this 'table'.

I wish to disable this functionality and looked at styles/templates but everything seems in order. I also removed the `Normal.dotm` file so Word would have to create a new one, without succes.

Any suggestions what this feature could be and how to terminate this?

[image]

Comment: Might be an add-in. To disable them all : *File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings... > Add-ins*, check "Disable all Application Add-ins", OK. Undo if it doesn't help.

Comment: @harrymc, thanks for the suggestion. They are disabled, yet still the same behaviour. I'm willing to run Quick Assist if you want a look?

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: No it does not do this in safe mode @harrymc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to File -> Options -> Advanced
- Uncheck `Show text boundaries`

[image]

Comment: Yes that was it. This was driving me mad.

Answer (score 1):

As booting in Safe Mode fixes the problem, this indicates
that some third-party application is responsible for this behavior.

To locate the problematic application, you may use the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

This utility shows all programs configured to run during system boot or login
in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*.

If some of the listed items have any connection with Word, you may disable
them, reboot, and check again.

If you can't detect the problematic product by logic alone, the hard way
is to turn off startup entries in bunches, drilling down to
the startup program that causes this behavior.

Once the problematic product is identified, it might
have some setting that can avoid the problem, or can be uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along.

Comment: The accepted answer is unaffected by Safe mode...

Comment: I went into safe-mode with `winword /safe` in de command bar. Hopefully that is what you meant. Either way, the outline was not applied then whilst it was in normal mode.